# 2D sprite in Unity is not displaying the picture I assigned to it

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

So, I just got started with Unity3D and I don't really know what I'm doing.

I'm following an online tutorial and so far I've downloaded an image, imported it as an asset, and dragged this asset onto the "sprite" box(under sprite renderer) where, apparently, we are supposed to drag a texture onto a sprite. When the tutorial does it...their image shows up in the scene. Mine, however doesn't.

When I click the little circle to the right of this, and go to the 'scene' tab, there is only an option that says 'none', while in the tutorial the image that is desired is also an option. I feel like fixing this will fix the problem.

Thanks

Comment: You must drag object from `project` panel to 'Hierarchy` panel and double click on that object in`Hierarchy` to focus on object in scene

Comment: It's already in the hierarchy, and I've focused it, but the image that I assigned it just isn't showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If image is not showing up when you're browsing for it Unity3D it means it has not been imported to project as **asset**.
To do so, from Unity3D editor go to folder Assets, right click and choose *Import New Asset*:

[image]

Also you need to browse in *Assets*, no idea why you're browsing in *Scene*.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. So I imported it as an "asset", and then dragged it into a new sprite, just for testing. Still doesn't work :/ . Here's a screenshot of my Unity, find anything particularly off? (And I am browsing under the assets tab when I click the little circle, but despite being highlighted, it doesn't show up as the image). http://imgur.com/3U5DsHf

Comment: Your GameObject with SpriteRenderer has position "Z" below zero. It means in 3D dimensional space it's behind the camera. Just set it above zero, for example to 1.
When you have problems with troubleshooting of elements display, use 'Scene' viewport and turn off 2D view so that you can is if anything is not behind camera/other elements.

Comment: If the problem persists, can you maybe upload the project/scene somewhere so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: I've set it above 0, yet the problem persists. I don't really have a place to upload it, sorry. But here's another screenshot of the project: http://imgur.com/vaJVkWY

Comment: That's interesting. Have you tried dragging sprite from Assets directly to Hierarchy window? http://3.1m.yt/flk4UKKTS.png
If it won't work, maybe try removing and then adding again the asset? Can't tell much more without scene included.

Comment: Ahhhhhh man. I changed the "layer" from "default" to "UI" and that fixed it. Damn. What a silly problem. Anyways, thanks for your persisted assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Fellow Unity noob here: I had the same problem and realized I was dragging the sprite onto the scene window onto my GUI....which was not the same XY coordinates my main camera was looking at.

Double click on your main camera object to see what it sees in scene view. Is your sprite in view? If its not, you will need to adjust the XY coordinates of your sprite.